# pyreadstat Import Error on Mac: mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')

Tags: python, macos

I have Mac and get the following error after trying to compile:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/fatihshen/Documents/magicstat_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyreadstat/pyreadstat.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/fatihshen/Documents/magicstat_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyreadstat/pyreadstat.cpython-310-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/pyreadstat.cpython-310-darwin.so' (no such file)
```

My Mac environment:
MacOS Monterey
Version 12.2
Apple M1 Pro

That doesn't give any error on my Windows environment.

I am using PyCharm, with the Python version 3.9.5 in a virtual environment. I run "pip install pyreadstat" command on the terminal to install this package.

My guess is that there should be a pyreadstat version specifically built for M1 chip.

Is this a bug or am I missing something? Any ideas how I can overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there are currently no wheels avaiable for M1 on pypi, please install with conda instead.

The problem is being tracked [here](https://github.com/multi-build/multibuild/issues/457)